# Core Data one-to-many relationship NSSet with specific type?

Tags: swift, one-to-many, relationships, nsset

Can somebody explain me what I'm doing wrong? I'm beginner with Swift and I'm trying implement Core Data to my finished App.
In my example I have 3 classes: Month, Week and Day.
Month had an array [Week] and class Week had an array [Day]

```
class Month {
  var weeks: [Week]
}

class Week {
  var days: [Day]
}

class Day {
  var name: String
}
```

Now when I try to deal with Core Data and I made relationships one-to-many with NSManagedObject Subclasses I have NSSet instead of my arrays [Week] or [Day].

This NSSet has no type (objects are AnyObject) and it makes my app full of errors.

Does it really have to be a NSSet in this situation to deal with Core Data? Can I somehow set a type for NSSet collection? As you probably know NSSet doesn't work ;)
Help me guys, you are experts. I don't want change almost all code of my application :(

Most of problems are with FOR loops where I have to change

```
for week in month.weeks {
  for day in week.day{
    day.name = "something"
  }
}
```

to

```
for weekObject in month.weeks {
   let week = weekObject as! Week
   for dayObject in week.day {
      let day = dayObject as! Day
      day.name = "something"
   }
}
```

Comment: "As you probably know NSSet doesn't work ;)" Actually I don't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a typed Set instead:

```
@NSManaged var weeks: Set<Week>
```